# upload mutiple selected files to web server with php

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I have a php form which allows the user to provide a reference number and then select a pdf file to upload.

The form has multiple selections and as such I want to be able to upload multiple file with one form.

my form code is as below:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="capturelocal2.php">
<table id="hor-minimalist-a" border=0>
<tr><th><font color=red><b>Drop 1</b></font></th></tr>
<tr id="r0">
<th valign=bottom>Haulier Delivery #</th>
<th valign=bottom>Hulamin Load # A</th>
<th valign=bottom>Load # A POD</th>
<th valign=bottom>Hulamin Load # B</th>
<th valign=bottom>Load # B POD</th>
<th valign=bottom>Customer</th>
<th valign=bottom>Arrive Time</th>
<th valign=bottom>Depart Time</th>
</tr>
<tr id="r1">
<td valign=bottom  width=50><input type=text name=drop1del id=drop1del size=12></td>
<td valign=bottom  width=50><input type=text name=ref1 id=ref1 size=12></td>
<td valign=bottom  width=50><input type=file size=6 name=ref1pod id=ref1pod></td>
<td valign=bottom  width=50><input type=text name=ref1b id=ref1b size=12></td>
<td valign=bottom  width=50><input type=file size=6 name=ref1bpod id=ref1bpod></td>
<td>
    <SELECT NAME="drop1" id="drop1"  style="width:200px;" > 
    <OPTION VALUE=0>
    <?=$optionscustomers?> 
    </SELECT> 
</td>
<td><input type=text name="drop1arrivedatetime" id="drop1arrivedatetime" size=15><img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('drop1arrivedatetime','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24')"  style="cursor:pointer"/></td>
<td><input type=text name="drop1departdatetime" id="drop1departdatetime" size=15><img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('drop1departdatetime','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24')"  style="cursor:pointer"/></td>
</tr>
<tr><th><font color=red><b>Drop 2</b></font></th></tr>
<tr id="r2">
<th valign=bottom>Haulier Delivery #</th>
<th valign=bottom>Hulamin Load # A</th>
<th valign=bottom>Load # A POD</th>
<th valign=bottom>Hulamin Load # B</th>
<th valign=bottom>Load # B POD</th>
<th valign=bottom>Customer</th>
<th valign=bottom>Arrive Time</th>
<th valign=bottom>Depart Time</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr id="r3">
<td valign=bottom><input type=text name=drop2del id=drop2del size=12></td>
<td valign=bottom  width=50><input type=text name=ref2 id=ref2 size=12></td>
<td valign=bottom  width=50><input type=file size=5 name=ref2pod id=ref2pod></td>
<td valign=bottom  width=50><input type=text name=ref2b id=ref2b size=12></td>
<td valign=bottom  width=50><input type=file size=5 name=ref2bpod id=ref2bpod></td>
<td>
    <SELECT NAME="drop2" id="drop2" style="width:200px;"  > 
    <OPTION VALUE=0>
    <?=$optionscustomers?> 
    </SELECT> 
</td>
<td><input type=text name="drop2arrivedatetime" id="drop2arrivedatetime" size=15><img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('drop2arrivedatetime','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24')"  style="cursor:pointer"/></td>
<td><input type=text name="drop2departdatetime" id="drop2departdatetime" size=15><img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('drop2departdatetime','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24')"  style="cursor:pointer"/></td>
</tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

My PHP Code to process the form is:

```
    $ref1 = $_POST[ref1];
    $ref1pod = $_POST[ref1pod];
    $ref1bpod = $_POST[ref1bpod];
    $ref2 = $_POST[ref2];
    $ref2pod = $_POST[ref2pod];
    $ref2bpod = $_POST[ref2bpod];

    if (isset(ref1pod) || ($_FILES["ref1pod"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
      || ($_FILES["ref1pod"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
      && ($_FILES["ref1pod"]["size"] < 50000))
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ref1pod"]["tmp_name"],
        "/home/hulaminyxr/public_html/pod/" . ($ref1pod.".pdf"));
        echo "POD Successfully uploaded for delivery $ref1pod:<br><br>"; 
        }

    if (isset($ref1bpod) ||($_FILES["ref1bpod"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
      || ($_FILES["ref1bpod"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
      && ($_FILES["ref1bpod"]["size"] < 50000))
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ref1bpod"]["tmp_name"],
        "/home/hulaminyxr/public_html/pod/" . ($ref1bpod.".pdf"));
        echo "POD Successfully uploaded for delivery $ref1bpod:<br><br>"; 
    }

 if (isset(ref2pod) || ($_FILES["ref2pod"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
      || ($_FILES["ref2pod"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
      && ($_FILES["ref2pod"]["size"] < 50000))
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ref2pod"]["tmp_name"],
        "/home/hulaminyxr/public_html/pod/" . ($ref2.".pdf"));
        echo "POD Successfully uploaded for delivery $ref2:<br><br>"; 
        }

    if (isset($ref2bpod) ||($_FILES["ref2bpod"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
      || ($_FILES["ref2bpod"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
      && ($_FILES["ref2bpod"]["size"] < 50000))
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ref2bpod"]["tmp_name"],
        "/home/hulaminyxr/public_html/pod/" . ($ref2b.".pdf"));
        echo "POD Successfully uploaded for delivery $ref2bpod:<br><br>"; 
    }  


    echo "<br><br>All files uploaded successfully";
```

Currently, on submitting the form the pdf file is not being uploaded correctly? is my code correct or is this not possible with multiple files?

In addition, I have 10 rows in the form, I have only provided the code for 1 row, is there a more efficient way to uplaod mutiple selected files?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is possible to upload multiple files. Please read the [PHP manual for uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)
2. If your code is not working please explain what is the problem.
3. Your code is saving jpeg files as pdf. See my comments below:

   ```
   # If file type is "pdf" or "jpeg" save it...
   if (isset(ref1pod) || ($_FILES["ref1pod"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
         || ($_FILES["ref1pod"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
         && ($_FILES["ref1pod"]["size"] < 50000))
         {

     # .. with .pdf extension
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ref1pod"]["tmp_name"],
       "/home/hulaminyxr/public_html/pod/" . ($ref1pod.".pdf"));
   ```

   `